# Use Two Database Connections through a PHP Class? (PHP / MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, class, this

I have created these two files:

```
class myDbClass {
        function dbConnect($db) {
            $dbhost = 'myhost';
            $dbuser = 'myuser';
            $dbpass = 'mypassword';
            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');      
            mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

        $this->dbConnection = $conn; 
    }

function dbSelect($sql) {       

    // run the query
    if ($result = mysql_query($sql, $this->dbConnection)) { 
        echo 'got a result';
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }


} // end of dbSelect function
} // end of class
```

and

```
    include "myclass.php";

    // create two new objects

$db1 = new mkaDB();
    $db2 = new mkaDB();

// First Database Connection
$dbname1 = 'myfirstdatabase';
$db1->dbConnect($dbname1);


// Second Database Connection
$dbname2 = 'myseconddatabase';
$db2->dbConnect($dbname2);

$sql1 = "select * from mytable";
$db1->dbSelect($sql1);

$sql2 = "select * from myothertable";
$db2->dbSelect($sql2);
```

What I am trying to accomplish is creating 2 database connections, each connection to a different schema. I then want to be able to call each schema via the `$db1->dbSelect` or `$db2->dbSelect`. However, when I run this I get the "error" message from the `dbSelect` function. If I block out all calls to the `$db2` object, the `$db1` object does work.

I thought I could use `$this->dbConnection` to keep things sorted out, but this does not appear to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the 4th, "new_link" parameter ([php mysql_connect](https://www.php.net/mysql_connect)):

"If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned. The new_link parameter modifies this behavior and makes mysql_connect() always open a new link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same parameters."

Comment: That did the trick. I changed `$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)` to `$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, true)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this:

```
    class sql
{

    private static function _dbConnect()
    {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "uname", "pwd");
        mysql_select_db("db");
    }
private static function _dbConnect2()
    {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "uname", "pwd");
        mysql_select_db("db");
    }


public static function something($user){
            self::_dbConnect
           // code in here and mysql
          OR
            self::_dbConnect2
```

}

Something like that?

Worked example:

```
public static function getFriendNumber($username)
{
    self::_dbConnect();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM users WHERE `user_name` = '$username'")or die(mysql_error("Error selecting friend_array with id " . $username));
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $friend_delimit = $row['friend_array']; 
    }
    if($friend_delimit != ''){
        $explosion = explode(",",$friend_delimit);
        $counted = count($explosion);
        return $counted;
    }
    else {
        $counted = '0';
        return $counted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your $this->dbConnection is not defined within your class.

```
class myDbClass {
  private $dbConnection
  ....
}
```